# Underscore how to use the each and sort multiple array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have 2 sets in an array, each of these sets is an array of objects. I'd like to sort both of them using `_.each` and return a sorted object with the following:

```
var O1 = [{'name':'one'}, {'name':'two'}, {'name':'three'}, {'name':'four'}, {'name':'five'}, {'name':'six'}];
var O2 = [{'name':'rat'}, {'name':'cat'}, {'name':'lion'}, {'name':'tiger'}, {'name':'dog'}, {'name':'horse'}];

var sortIt = [O1, O2];

_.each(sortIt, function(item){
    item = _.sortBy(item, function(arr){
        return arr.name;
    })
    return item;
})

console.log(O1, "\n", O2); //nothing changed!
```

... but, apparently, nothing changes. The question is, what should be the proper approach?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/Qtskg/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, it's kind of useless checking the values of `O1` and `O2` *variables* after the sorting process - they won't change. See, `_.sortBy` doesn't order the given array in place (as native `Array#sort` does), instead it returns a new (sorted) copy.

Second, it makes little sense to return anything from `_.each` iterator function - it'll just be ignored.

Finally, to adjust the specific element of a list, you'll need to address that element; just reassigning some value to a param variable (`item` in your code) won't be enough.

Here's one approach to do what you want:

```
var sortIt = [O1, O2];
_.each(sortIt, function(item, index, list) {
    list[index] = _.sortBy(item, function(arr) {
        return arr.name;
    });
})

console.log(sortIt); // something is definitely changed now!
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtskg/2/).